# Mysql REPLACE not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, replace, sql-update

For some reason my script isn't deleting existing rows when I'm using replace.

I'm working on an inventory management system, and I may be calling this script every hour or so to update the db:

```
   REPLACE INTO inventory(username, sku,asin,set_price,inventory)
                   VALUES('trav','AEG5502','B00875JE0C','23.49','');
```

but instead of deleting the old row, it creates a new row with the exact same info.

I'm sure it's a simple error, but I would love if someone could help me out.

Additional info, a row has about 15 columns.  None of these columns (`username`, `sku`,`asin`,`set_price,inventory`) are a `primary key`, I don't know if that has to be the case for replace to work, but I thought I'd mention it.

Thanks

Comment: REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

Comment: Offtopic. But I see you insert a username into the row. It's wiser to include a user_id instead of a name. What if the username changes?

Comment: @bart: assuming proper foreign key setups, you can cascade such a change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RTLM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html   `replace` will only replace if ANY of the fields you're using are the primary or at least a unique key in the table. since none of your fields are, it simply does an insert

Comment: Shoot, I guess I didn't think about that when I setup the database.  Thanks for the help though!  Is there any way to simulate a sku being unique if username = trav?  I'm guessing that some users will have the same sku numbers.

Comment: offhand guess: slap a unique index on the (username,sku) tuple?